# Typeorm Postgis order by nearest Point

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, postgis, typeorm

I have a postgis database with a bunch of points and I would like to get the points in order of the distance to my own position (longitude and latitude).

So I want to do something like:

```
const markers = await this.markerRepo.find({
  where: {
    type: "test"
  },
  order: { position: 'ASC' },
});
```

But I want to order them in relation to my current position.

This id my table entity (Nestjs):

```
@Entity()
 export class Marker {
   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
   id: number;

   @Column({
     type: 'geography',
     spatialFeatureType: 'Point',
     srid: 4326,
     nullable: true,
   })
   position: Point;
 
   @Column()
   type: string;
 }
```

If you need any more information please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out Typeorm does not support Postgis (Who would have thought)

The solution is to just send a SQL request like this:

```
const markers = await this.markerRepo.query(
  `SELECT * , ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(${yourLatitude}, ${yourLongitude} ), position) AS dist FROM marker ORDER BY dist LIMIT 10;`,
);
```